# How to pass a Lambda to toSortedSet() in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin, functional-interface

I'm a little confused why this doesn't work. I'm having a simple `Iterable` of `String` that I want to sort via `toSortedSet()` my own way. I wanted to pass a lambda to it like this:

```
myStringIterable.toSortedSet({a,b -> a.compareTo(b)})
```

That, however, doesn't seem to work. The error says

> Type mismatch. Required kotlin.Comparator < String>
>
> Found: (String,String) -> Int

A Comparator is a *Functional Interface*, so I should be able to pass it as a Lambda, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.2, SAM conversion is only supported for Java interfaces. `kotlin.Comparator` is an interface defined in Kotlin, and for such interfaces there is no support for converting lambdas to implementations of those interfaces.

Comment: Isn't it a good counterexample to "since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary"? Should all standard library methods taking `Comparator` get overloads (or extension function "overloads") taking functions?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov it's very likely that we will add support for SAM conversion of Kotlin interfaces in a future language version, so I don't think it makes sense to add these overloads now. and there are enough comparator-making facilities in the standard library to cover the current needs

Comment: That's very nice to hear!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) to wrap code into `Comparator`s:

```
toSortedSet(compareBy { it.length })
```

I think in your case, no argument is necessary for `toSortedSet` though.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it might not completely answer what the OP is really asking, i.e. *why* a simple lambda doesn't work. For simple field selection, `compareBy` works, but what if the OP wanted a complex calculation for the comparison?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. As DodgyCodeException pointed out, though, my actual case is a little more complex, so I just reduced it to a example with `String`s since the issue why it wouldn't accept lambdas is the same.

Answer (score 2):

yole already provided the why, and here is the how:

```
setOf("a", "b", "c").toSortedSet(object: Comparator<String>{
    override fun compare(s1: String, s2: String): Int {
        return s1.compareTo(s2) // replace with own logic
    }
})
```

Or like this:

```
val comp = object: Comparator<String> {
    override fun compare(s1: String, s2: String): Int {
        return s2.compareTo(s1) // replace with own logic
    }
}

sortedSetOf(comp, "a", "b", "c")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is new, but you can do:

```
val set = listOf("a", "c", "b").toSortedSet(Comparator { s1, s2 ->
    s1.compareTo(s2) // replace with own logic
})
```